# Azure node.js app hosting

Tags: node.js, azure, hosting

Getting error: 'site' is not an azure command. on command "D:\harshit\course project\node-login-master\azure>azur t error:   'site' is not an azure command. See 'azure he The current mode is: arm (Azure Resource Manager).  D:\harshit\course project\node-login-master\azure>" to host app on azure what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Azure-CLI to create a Web App and attempt to deploy a node.js application on it.

According your error message, your CLI is in `ARM` mode. Switch to `ASM` mode using `azure config mode asm`. Then you can execute command `azure site` for the list of site operations.

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/ for getting started on Azure Web Apps on Node.js.

Comment: As if it works for you, you can mark it as an answer, which will be easier searched by the communities who have the same issue with you.